# How does a new ASP.NET MVC 5 application know how to create a database and how does the Account Controller access the database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I created an ***ASP.NET MVC 5*** Application using ***Visual Studio 2013 Update 2***. In the application, I have an Account controller. It's different from what I am used to and does not 
contain an instantiation of ***dbcontext***.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

My `web.config` that is created by default has a connection string like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20140417072624.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20140417072624;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Can someone explain to me how the application knows to create a database for this application when it starts for the first time?

Also, on subsequent starts, does it use Entity Framework to access the Identity tables to do the authentication?

Comment: See `IdentityModel.cs` in folder `Models` in the MVC template.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**1) WHAT'S GOING ON HERE:**

When you create a new ***MVC 5*** application and choose "*Individual User Accounts*", a new ***ASP.NET Identity Provider*** is included which uses ***Entity Framework 6 Code-First***.

Microsoft has adopted *EF-Code-First* to make *Identity* as customizable as possible.

When Identity is accessed for the first time, ***Entity Framework*** checks to see if the database exists. Unless configured otherwise, it uses the `"DefaultConnection"` to find the identity database. If the database does not exist when Identity is called, *EF* automatically created the database.

Notice your connection string contains

```
`AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20140417072624.mdf`
```

If you open your ***App_Data*** Folder, you should have a *aspnet-WebApplication3-20140417072624.mdf* file.

If you double click on this **.mdf** file, the ***VS2013 Server Explorer*** will open your DB. If you have already attempted to access any Identity functionality, you will these tables created:

- ***_MigrationHistory***
- ***ASPNetRoles***
- ***ASPNetUserClaims***
- ***ASPNetUserLogins***
- ***ASPNetUsers***

By default, your app is configured to use ***SQL Server Compact*** (MDF file) so you don't have to have an actual ***SQL Server*** Instance running. All of this is customizable. The name of your MDF file, the schema of Identity Database, the choice of ***SQL Compact*** vs an actual ***SQL Server*** instance. Change your Connection String, or create a new one and pass this new connection to your context.

---

**2) WHERE IS MY CONTEXT?**

All this is well and good, but an important question you asked is basically "**Where is my context?**", and the just as relevant implied questions regarding how you can further customize your DB or alter validation logic.

You will notice that your project references `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`. This assembly is an implementation of `IdentityDBContext<TUser>` and implentation of `UserManager` Class.

Open your ***AccountController***, and notice the constructor has `UserManager` object passed which in turn has a `new UserStore` object passed, which gets passed a `ApplicationDbContext`.

```
    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
```

The `ApplicationDbContext` is defined in your **Models** Folder. Inside that folder, you will find an ***IdentityModels.cs*** file. Open it and you will see

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

This is where your Identity Context is assigned. you can change the connection name passed to the `ApplicationDbContext` constructor, or define and use a different context in your account controller.

---

**3) HOW DO I CUSTOMIZE MY IDENTITY SCHEMA?**

Another class defined IN ***IdentityModels.cs*** file is the `ApplicationUser` class which inherits from `IdentityUser` class.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Any properties you add to this class will be persisted in your ***ASPNetUsers*** Table. The rest of the schema is defined in `IdentityDbContext` class. So, while you can add more tables (e.g. Privileges) to your Identity Schema by adding a DBSet to the Context Definition,

```
public DBSet<Privileges> { get; set; }
```

Altering other tables (Roles, Claims, etc) is also possible, but far more involved. For example, to customize the **Roles** table, you would have to implement a `NewIdentityRole` inheriting from `IdentityRole` and add it's relationship by overriding the `OnModelCreating()` method for your Context.

This article on **[Customizing Roles Tables](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/13/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-Roles.aspx)** does a good job of describing the steps involved. Even here, you will find that there is significant trouble invested into simply ADDING new columns. Removing tables or columns from the original schema created in the `IdentityDbContext` class is probably as much trouble as creating your own implementation of `IdentityDbContext` class.

Comment: Dave. Thanks for your help and advice. I checked and I think some of your explanation no longer applies to the latest templates used with MVC5 and the VS2013 Update 2. This combination uses ASP.NET Identity 2 but I think some of your explanation refers to the older Identity model.

Comment: @Melina, please expand on that. I described the environment I'm on which I think has all the latest nuget updates. If any advances have happened I'm not aware of, I'd like to understand more...

Comment: I just checked a bit more into what the RC for update 2 offers and I think I will stay away from that for a while. As far as I can see the account controller appears not to be finished. They made a lot of changes on the account controller but it appears to lack a login method and when I start up the same application there's no "login" or "register" links to click. Seems like the RC is a WIP :-(  Will accept your answer as it applies to what most people are using. thanks

Comment: @Behzad, please explain downvote. Seems like you didn't like my criticism of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it would be in the `ApplicationUserManager`, My guess is that this is a service which utilizes the db context in order to manage the application users.

You can right click on this Class and click `Go to definition` and keep doing that until you can see the class which initializes the database.

Also, in MVC 4 the initialization is done in a Filter Attribute. So look in the Filter folder if there is one. I know it's not MVC 5. But it could still be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

As Melina pointed out, the original question referenced the current ASP.NET Identity 2.x model.

Dave Alperovich's answer provided valuable background information on the concepts behind ASP.NET Identity, although the examples were drawn from ASP.NET Identity 1.x, which was replaced in 2014.

Callum Linington provides the "teach a man to fish" answer.  By following his advice, it's easy to see that the 2.x "ApplicationUserManager" class is derived from a 1.x-style "UserManager".

The answer is basically that the "ApplicationUserManager", which is injected as a parameter when "AccountController" is created, connects to the identity data store in its own constructor:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

Note how this "hidden" 2.x code is very similar to the 1.x code as given above:

```
public AccountController()
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
```

Comment: thanks Scott for helping with your comment. If you look at the edit history of this question, you would see that I added the bolded reference to Ver 2.x. I'm not sure how long you've been programming, but, at the time I answered this question, version 2.x was still a work in progress. I hate to be fussy about these things, but I suggest you put such "non-answers" or "comments" into the **comment** section. You see, when people come here for answers, SO doesn't want he **answer section** polluted with "comments". I don't think they suspend over a thing like this, by they're kinda anal about it

Comment: Scott,

I admire your stance on "teaching the man to fish". As you progress through your career, you'll find most "software engineers" wait around for someone to answer all their question. A great way to advance your technical knowledge is by trying to answer questions of people with more experience than you!