# Having two dbcontext files for entity framework is causing me problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My ultimate goal is to create a relationship to 'AspNetUsers' like in the picture below. Only instead of 'Address' my entity is 'YogaSpace'. 
[image]

Here is where I'm having problems. And here is what I've done so far.
First I created the properties in my two entities seen below.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //code here left out
    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; }
    //code here left out
}

public class YogaSpace
{
    // all other code left out to save space
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Now I go and update my database in package manager and I receive the error messages seen below. It says I have no keys defined for certain entities.
[image]

So I googled it and added this code below to my YogaBandyContext.cs file below.
***NOTE** - this is in my DataAccess assembly

```
namespace YogaBandy.DataAccess.Context
{
public class YogaBandyContext : DbContext
{
    public YogaBandyContext()
        : base("name=YogaBandyDatabase")
    {
    }

    //}
    // code left out here to save space
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
}
```

}

I updated my database and **NOTHING** happened. Then I realized I have another dbcontext class in 'IdentityModel.cs'. This file was created and came with the Asp.Net MVC 5 application. **WHICH I MOVED FROM THE MAIN ASSEMBLY OVER TO AN ASSEMBLY THAT CONTAINS ALL MY DOMAIN CLASSES** This is IdentityModel.cs and it's in the 'DomainClasses' assembly.

```
namespace YogaBandy.DomainClasses.Models
{
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //other members here left out to save space
    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("YogaBandyDatabase", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
}
```

}

I tried updating the database again with no luck. I still get the errors that no keys are defined.

Question - so where am I having problems creating a reference to AspNetUsers and why can't I create the necessary keys? Is it because I have two context files and they are in two assemblies that are not part of the asp.net mvc 5 project, they are in libraries. I looked at my db and it looks like there are already keys defined for these entities shown below, right? So what the hell is going on here?
[image]

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be having two of the same dbcontext, remove one of them, and from the look of it, you are adding new tables to the default user relation tables that came with mvc 5, so instead of creating a new dbcontext, your YogabrandyContext should inherit from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>. so on this line: public class YogaBandyContext : DbContext to public class YogaBandyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> and remove all modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId); because they are not necessary. I can provide with an example if needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a new ASP.NET MVC 5 application know how to create a database and how does the Account Controller access the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130795/how-does-a-new-asp-net-mvc-5-application-know-how-to-create-a-database-and-how-d)

Comment: Hi Eric, I did what you said and inherited IdentityDbContext in my YogaBandyContext class and I updated the db. I also commented out ApplicationDbContext in Identiotymodel.cs. But now there is a error saying 'There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.' Should I just delete the db and rebuild it?

Comment: First,
Add-Migration InitialMigrations -IgnoreChanges 
then
update-database -verbose
this should work... @user1186050