# Data is not entering in dbo.AspNetUsers (which is empty) and still showing that username is already taken ( while registering)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project which was almost complete. I didn't use SQL server, rather I used inbuilt database in Asp.net 4.5.1. At first everything was perfect - like when I am registering a user, `AspNetUsers` table gets updated. Now I deleted all the contents of my table and registering the same user - it says `name asag******@gmail.com has already taken`. Even if I registered new user, `AspNetUsers` table is not updated...

Code-(inbuilt)

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();

 var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = txtemailid.Text, Email = txtemailid.Text };

 IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, txtpass.Text);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
-
-
-
-
}
```

I am getting result =false. It says user already exists.

Comment: Maybe you get false for a different reason (can't find the database?) What library or database _are_ you using?

Comment: i am using (LocalDB)\v11.0 sql server database from vs 13. this code was working when i excecuted it a day before . but now its not working .                 +  it is taking those email addresses that i havent used on my system before . when i execute it on other system, i need to register again with the emailaddress that  has already been registered in the project on my system

Comment: So you _are_ using SQL Server? I don't think I can help much further but based on your description, it isn't using the database that you think it is. You need to ensure you understand which database is being used.

Comment: no i am not using sql server . and u are right that the data isn't going in the database . but i am not able to figure it out where the data is going , as i have added only one databse and used only one connection string.. is there any chance that data is being stored temporary somewhere else ??

Comment: Looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130795/how-does-a-new-asp-net-mvc-5-application-know-how-to-create-a-database-and-how-d I guess you have a web config just like that (which creates a MDF file - a SQL Server file). I suggest two things: 1. Delete the MDF file (apparently it will be recreated), 2. Change the connection string to point somewhere else and confirm the file is created.

Comment: Thank u .. Thanks a lot.. This solution actually worked . (deleting MDF file + changing connection string )  you saved my time @Nick.McDermaid.